# Python Numpy program output: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed numpy and write code but nothing get output. What should i do?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5])
print(arr)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you offer more details about your install and the error? Are you sure your install worked?

Comment: yes.I have installed numpy 1.18.4 and i write code in Pycharm with no syntax error but not getting output